# Objective-c setContentOffset method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am trying to convert code written in objective-c into Swift language. 
In following lines:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.mapView.frame.size.height*-1 ) {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x,   self.mapView.frame.size.height*-1)];

}
}
```

I encountered this parameter which should be, due to documentation, evaluated to boolean type

```
self.mapView.frame.size.height*-1
```

Can anybody tell me what's going on here and how this expression is evaluated to boolean? the pointer is the thing that unables me to convert it into Swift, could you help how to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error is because of no space between operator and object for an expression.

On compilation time compiler breaks this lines `self.mapView.frame.size.height* -1`. And what it gets 
`self.mapView.frame.size.height*` and `-1`. So compiler mis understand as two separate parameters here.

A space between `self.mapView.frame.size.height` and `*` required to tell the compiler that this is an expression to multiply `self.mapView.frame.size.height` with `-1` value.

So your relevant Swift code will be as below:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.mapView.frame.size.height * -1 ) {
        scrollView .setContentOffset(CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.mapView.frame.size.height * -1), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will vote your answer as soon as I'm able to!

Answer (score 1):

```
self.mapView.frame.size.height * -1
```

This is a multiplication.

Comment: Not sure, when I paste it in such form in Swift, Xcode calls "Missing argument for parameter "Animated" in call" - I guess if it was just a multiplication, It wouldn't cause any problems. Moreover, it should be evaluated to bool